# Recursively assign the value to a rdd in a loop in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As  described in the  title, how can I assign the value to a rdd variable?

My code is like this:

```
Var rdd1 ＝ something
For(i <- 0 to n){    
  rdd1＝ calculation(rdd1,other params)
  rdd1.first
}
```

When I use the code above, with a few iterations the ram memory is full and some rdds are written to disk even I called the `unpersist` function.

Comment: What is `Rdd.action` here and what type of calculation are you performing? It would be easier to see the problem if the actual code was added but you could use a fold operation if you want to avoid `var`: e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689131/how-to-overwrite-a-rdd-in-a-loop?rq=1

Comment: Could you correct your question? You have lot of formatting error. Also I would suggest to materialize your rdd using actions like rdd1.count() so that the calculation graph doesn't exceed beyond normal lengths. https://medium.com/@thejasbabu/rdds-building-block-of-spark-bf16136afbc6

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I have checked the answer before.  I call the action like first , count and save as text file but the memory is still high,causes writing rdd to disk and long time full gc ,executor lost